# Are two projections which are Murray-von-Neumann equivalent in $C(X,M_{n})$ approximately unitarily equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, projection-matrices

Let $A$ be the C$^{*}$-algebra $C(X,M_{n})$, where $X$ is a compact, connected metric space. Let 
$$
E=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 &\cdots & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Suppose $P\in A$ is a projection, which is Murray-von-Neumann equivalent to $E$. I.e., there is a $W\in A$ such that $P=WW^{*}$ and $E=W^{*}W$.

> Can we conclude that $P$ and $E$ are unitarily equivalent?

This question is a a more general version of a question I posted a few days ago: [Are These Projections Unitarily Equivalent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846704/are-these-projections-unitarily-equivalent)

Comment: If $\|P - UEU^\ast\| < 1/2$, then $P$ and $UEU^\ast$ are homotopy equivalent, and hence unitarily equivalent—see, for instance, section 2.2 of Rørdam–Larsen–Laustsen, _An introduction to K-theory for $C^\ast$-algebras_.

Comment: So I guess the question is equivalent to asking whether they are unitarily equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. Let $W : S^2 \to M_3(\mathbb{C})$ be the inclusion $$(x,y,z) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}x & 0 & 0 \\ y & 0 & 0\\ z & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$ so that $W \in M_3(C(S^2))$ is a partial isometry with $W^\ast W = E$ and $P := WW^\ast$ the projection corresponding to the complexified normal bundle of $S^2$ as the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose, by contradiction, that $E$ and $P$ are unitarily equivalent, so that $P = UEU^\ast$ for some unitary $U \in C(S^2,U(3))$. Then
$$
 I - P = I-UEU^\ast = U(I-E)U^\ast,
$$
so that $I-P$ and $I-E$ are unitarily equivalent, and hence that the corresponding vector bundles over $S^2$ are isomorphic. On the one hand, under Serre–Swan, the projection $I-E$ corresponds to the trivial subbundle $(\{0\} \times \mathbb{C}^2) \times S^2 \subset \mathbb{C}^3 \times S^2$, which has trivial top Chern class $c_2(\mathbb{C}^2 \times S^2) = 0$. On the other hand, under Serre–Swan, the projection $I-P$ corresponds to the complexified tangent bundle $T_{\mathbb{C}}S^2$ of $S^2$, but
$$
 \int_{S^2} c_2(T_{\mathbb{C}}S^2) = \int_{S^2}e(TS^2) = \chi(S^2) = 2 \neq 0,
$$
so that $T_{\mathbb{C}}S^2$ has non-vanishing top Chern class, and hence can't possibly be trivial. It is possible to rephrase all this in operator-algebraic terms, but you'd need $K$-theory and $K$-homology to do so. To cut a long story short, the projections $I-P$ and $I-E$ define classes $[I-P]$ and $[I-E]$ in the $K$-theory $K_0(C(S^2))$ of $C(S^2)$, which you can show are distinct by computing their pairings with the appropriate class in the $K$-homology $K^0(C(S^2))$.